# How to understand the tf.control_dependencies?

Tags: tensorflow

There is a very weird example:

```
w = tf.get_variable("w", shape=(), dtype=tf.int32,
                    initializer=tf.constant_initializer(2))

reset = tf.assign(w, 0)
update = tf.assign(w, w + 3)
update = tf.Print(update, [update])
reset = tf.Print(reset, [reset])
def body(i,x):
    with tf.control_dependencies([update]):
        t = tf.identity(w)

    with tf.control_dependencies([reset]):
        y = tf.identity(t)
    return i+1, y
i, z = tf.while_loop(lambda i,z: i < 20, body, [0,0])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(z))
```

The output is `5`. But how to explain it?
As we can see that `reset` is not executed and `update` is executed only once
utilizing `tf.Print`. But `tf.while_loop` will execute `body` 20 times. So it is amazing.

### update

Another weird [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4663#issuecomment-336504782):

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32)

old_val = tf.identity(x)
with tf.control_dependencies([old_val]):
    new_val = tf.assign(x, x + 1)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print(sess.run([old_val, new_val, x]))
```

The output is `[1,1,1]`. After looking the github issue, I am also confused.
`sess.run()` is executed one by one, which means it runs `old_val`, then `new_val` and then `x`.

When it runs `old_val`, it gets `0`, and when it runs `new_val`, it find `old_val` is dependencies of `new_val`, but `old_val` has been run. So it runs `new_val` immediately and gets `1`, and then runs `x`, gets `1`.

So I think it should print `[0,1,1]`, so what's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the explanation of why you get this result:

Let's follow the graph from the node you execute in the session and let's see what happens.

`sess.run(z)`

`z` is the second return variable of tf.while_loop, thus let's see what happens when we execute the `tf.while_loop` node.

## first iteration:

`tf.while_loop` executes the `body` function until the predicate is true. Thus, for this first call:

`body(i,x)` invocation -> the body of the `body` function has no reference to the `x` variable. Thus

`return i+1, y`

the while loop continues, passing now `y` as `x` in the body call.

## second iteration:

`body(i, x)`  = `run(body(_,`y`variable of the previous iteration))`

Now Tensorflow needs to resolve the `y` variable.

1. `y` variable is `tf.identity(t)`
2. `tf.identity(t)` must be executed after `reset = tf.assign(w,0)`.
3. `tf.identity(t)` references `t`. After executing `reset`, we have to resolve `t`, evaluate it and then exexute `y`.

Thus: `t = tf.identity(w)` -> only after the execution of `update`

Thus execute in this order: `update` -> `t` -> `reset` -> `y`

The evaluation produces: `w = w + 3 -> w = 5; t = 5; w = 0; y = t = 5; return 5.`

## Side effect

the `update` and `reset` nodes are declared outside the body function, this means that these are just 2 independent nodes and that now they're marked as **executed** (conceptually).

## Third iteration

the evaluation order is the same from the previous iteration, BUT: the `update` and `reset` nodes have been already executed (because the executed flag is present), thus `tf.control_dependencies` skips their execution and Tensorflow executes only `t` and `y`.

Thus: `t = 5; y = 5; return 5`.

As you can see, from now on you'll get `5` as a result, always.

Comment: I use `reset = tf.Print(reset, [reset])`, but it don't output anything, so I think `reset` op isn't  executed.  And what do you mean `Side effect`, the `tf.control_dependencies` just execute `dependencies` once? Does doc declare? I  am also confused.

Comment: I have another question, please see my update, thanks!